# How to add column in Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have written an new plugin 'Upload File' which have its own button jut like 'Build', 'Release', 'Rebuild' plugin. Now, I want to restrict access to plugin for different users. There are columns in **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy**. This column contains 'Overall', 'Credentials', 'Run', 'View', etc. I want to add new column for Upload. How do I do this?

It is present in Jenkins -> Configure Global Security

Answer (score 0):

When you setup permissions for your plugin, you need to establish a **permission group**. The **title of the permission group** is what appears in the column headers then.

Example:

```
[...]
import hudson.security.PermissionGroup;
import hudson.security.Permission;
import hudson.security.PermissionScope;
[...]

public class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    // create permission group
    private static final PermissionGroup pg =
      new PermissionGroup( MyPlugin.class,
                           Messages._MyPermissionGroupTitle() // This is the column title
                         );

    // setup permission in that group
    public static final Permission perm =
        new Permission( pg,
                        "MyPermission",
                        Messages._MyPermissionDescription(),
                        Jenkins.ADMINISTER
                      );
}
```